# jQuery append the data from array to the corresponding indexed element

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, appendto

Following is my backend generated HTML code, so I've no control on it. If there are N entries at backend it will create N elements with class `row` and an element inside it with the classname `itemN`. This complete markup is wrapped in the container having class `grid`. As you can see in the below markup, all the elements are empty, there is no text inside those elements.

Here is the markup for 6 items.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For N elements markup from backend, I'm also getting the equal number of element's array as follow.

```
var grid = new Array('some_data3', 'some_data1', 'some_data2', 'some_data4', 'some_data6', 'some_data5');
```

Coming to the question, I want to append the data from the array to the elements of that number in the HTML markup. Ex. the first element with the class `item1` should have the `some_data3`-first(*i.e. 0th indexed*) element from the array.

How can i append that array to .grid by using jQuery?

Comment: It is not completely clear what you are trying to do - can you add desired output? Should 'some_data1' (btw, is it text or some html) be inside 'item1' div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps/Suggestions:**

1. You can use [**attribute-value**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector to select all the element whose class starts with some value. `$('.grid [class^="item"]')` will select all the elements inside the `.grid` elements whose classname starts with `item`.
2. Use the index value inside the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/), to get the data from the array.
3. Use [`append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) or `html`/`text` to add the data to the element.
4. I will also recommend you to use array literal syntax to define array instead of `Array` constructor

**Demo**

```js
// Array of data
var grid = ['some_data3', 'some_data1', 'some_data2', 'some_data4', 'some_data6', 'some_data5'];

// For all the elements inside the .grid element whose classname starts with `item`
$('.grid [class^="item"]').each(function(i) {
  // i is the index inside the loop
  // Append the data from array at index i to the current element
  $(this).append(grid[i]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item4"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```